# Convert Integer (0,1,2...,23) to hour (AM/PM)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a dataset with 1 column of SQL hour integer values (0, 1, 2, ... , 23). Is there any way to convert these to: 12:00am, 1:00am, 2:00am, ... , 11:00pm ??

Answer (score 2):

You can append `:00:00` to the integer, and use `CAST` to convert it to `time`, like this:

```
SELECT CAST( CAST(int_val as VARCHAR(2))+':00:00' as time)
FROM my_table
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c321/9)

When you upgrade to SQL Server 2012, you would be able to use [`TIMEFROMPARTS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx) function to do the same thing without the unnecessary conversions:

```
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(int_val, 0, 0, 0, 0)
FROM my_table
```

Comment: This still isn't quite what they're after; output is e.g. `13:00:00.0000000`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand This gives OP a value of type "time", which he can convert to any reasonable representation as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This expression should work:

```
CASE WHEN [Hour] = 0 THEN '12:00am'
     WHEN [Hour] < 12 THEN CAST([Hour] AS VarChar) + ':00am'
     WHEN [Hour] = 12 THEN '12:00pm'
     ELSE CAST(([Hour]-12) AS VarChar) + ':00pm'
END AS [Time]
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL it's always going to be the "hard way". Here's one option (assuming the column with the number is called `num`):

```
SELECT CAST(num AS VARCHAR) + ':00' +
  CASE WHEN NUM < 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END Time
```

See a [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80afe/14) on SQLFiddle.

Comment: CONCAT does not exist in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @aaron I confess I've never used SQL Server - is that correct now?

Comment: No, this will yield to an invalid operation (you can't add an integer and a string). You can try your solutions at http://sqlfiddle.com/ before posting them...

Answer (score 0):

You really, really, really should be formatting this on the client. This isn't really a tidy job for SQL Server and I don't understand the purpose of doing it in T-SQL.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(i INT);

INSERT @t(i) VALUES(0),(1),(2), ... ,(23);

SELECT LOWER(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(19),DATEADD(HOUR,i,0),0),7)) FROM @t ORDER BY i;
```

Results:

```
12:00am
 1:00am
 2:00am
...
11:00pm
```

Comment: Totally agreed. Just need a quick solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (probably too complicated):

```
SELECT Hour,
       CASE WHEN Hour = 0 THEN '12:00AM'
         ELSE CASE WHEN Hour = 12 THEN '12:00PM' 
         ELSE CASE WHEN Hour < 12
            THEN CAST(Hour AS VARCHAR(7)) + ':00AM'
            ELSE CAST(Hour - 12 AS VARCHAR(7)) + ':00PM'
         END END END AS AM_PM
FROM dbo.Time
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6e49/6/0)</kbd>